# Boost ASIO crashes while calling callback function

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost, crash, boost-asio

I am new to boost library. I have written a server using boost beast async methods, but sometimes it got crashed. The scenario is not common, sometime it will take 3-4 hr to get crashed. I am sharing the screenshot of crash point which I got from application crashed dump file.

Please help me to find the reason of the crash.

[image]

I have done some research on google and also check this link "https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp" but not able to understand it.

Header file **WebSocketServer.h**

```
#include "server_certificate.hpp"
#include "xlogger.h"
#include "TSWebSocket.h"

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/dispatch.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the WEBSOCKETSERVER_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// WEBSOCKETSERVER_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef WEBSOCKETSERVER_EXPORTS
#define WEBSOCKETSERVER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WEBSOCKETSERVER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
class WebSocketSession;
// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class WEBSOCKETSERVER_API WebSocketListener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<WebSocketListener>
{
private:
    
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> m_pEvent;
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_hCSClientidSession;
    std::map<UINT, std::shared_ptr<WebSocketSession>> m_mapClientidSession;
public:
    WebSocketListener(tcp::endpoint endpoint);
    ~WebSocketListener();
    void Run();
    void setEventHandler(std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent);
    bool SendMessageToClient(UINT uClientid, std::string strMessage);
    bool RemoveClient(UINT uClientid);
private:
    void do_accept();
    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket);
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class WebSocketSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<WebSocketSession>
{
    websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer m_ReadBuffer;
    beast::flat_buffer m_WriteBuffer;
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> m_pEvent;
    SOCKET m_SocketDescriptor;
    bool bHandShake;
public:
    // Take ownership of the socket
    WebSocketSession(tcp::socket&& socket, ssl::context& ctx, std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent, SOCKET socketId);
    void run();
    void closeSocket();
    void on_run();
    void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec);
    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec);
    void on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t);
    void do_read();
    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    UINT getSocketDescriptor();
    bool SendMessageToClient(std::string strMessage);
    void do_Disconnect();
    ~WebSocketSession();
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Factory function that creates instances of the Server Protocol object.
WEBSOCKETSERVER_API std::shared_ptr<WebSocketListener> __stdcall InitializeWebSocketListener(unsigned short port, int maxThreads, std::string certificate, std::string privateKey);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Source File **WebSocketServer.cpp**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "WebSocketServer.h"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define NO_OF_THREAD 50

static std::shared_ptr<WebSocketListener> objWebSocketListener = nullptr;

// The io_context is required for all I/O
boost::asio::io_context g_ioc{ NO_OF_THREAD };

// The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
ssl::context g_ctx{ ssl::context::tlsv12 };

tcp::acceptor g_acceptor(net::make_strand(g_ioc));
http::request<http::string_body> g_upgrade_request;

void RunIOContextThread();

//It initialize the WebSocketListener
 std::shared_ptr<WebSocketListener> __stdcall InitializeWebSocketListener(unsigned short port, int maxThreads, std::string certificate, std::string privateKey)
{
    auto const address = net::ip::make_address("0.0.0.0");
    
    // This holds the self-signed certificate used by the server
    load_server_certificate(g_ctx, certificate, privateKey);

    // Create and launch a listening port
    objWebSocketListener = std::make_shared<WebSocketListener>(tcp::endpoint{ address, port });
    if(objWebSocketListener)
        objWebSocketListener->Run();

    // Run the I/O service on the requested number of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREAD; ++i)
    {
        std::thread ioContextThread(&RunIOContextThread);
        ioContextThread.detach();
    }

    return objWebSocketListener->shared_from_this();
}

void RunIOContextThread()
{
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "RunIOContextThread thread started %d", std::this_thread::get_id());
    g_ioc.run();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Listener class
WebSocketListener::~WebSocketListener()
{
}

WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener(tcp::endpoint endpoint) :
    m_pEvent(NULL)
{
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Constuctor Enter");
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
    beast::error_code ec;

    // Open the acceptor
    g_acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener open failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Allow address reuse
    g_acceptor.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener set_option failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }


    g_acceptor.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener set_option(No delay) failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Bind to the server address
    g_acceptor.bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener bind failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    g_acceptor.listen(net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener listen failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Started listening at %s:%hu", g_acceptor.local_endpoint().address().to_string().c_str(), g_acceptor.local_endpoint().port());
    }

    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Constuctor Leave");
}

bool WebSocketListener::RemoveClient(UINT uClientid) 
{
    bool bRet = false;
    try
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
        auto iter = m_mapClientidSession.find(uClientid);
        if (iter != m_mapClientidSession.end())
        {
            iter->second->closeSocket();
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketListener::RemoveClient Removed from map uClientid : %d refCount: %d", uClientid, iter->second.use_count());
            m_mapClientidSession.erase(iter);
            bRet = true;
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::RemoveClient Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::RemoveClient Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    return bRet;
}

bool WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient(UINT uClientid, std::string strMessage)
{
    bool bRet = false;
    try
    {

        EnterCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
        auto iter = m_mapClientidSession.find(uClientid);
        if (iter != m_mapClientidSession.end())
        {
            bRet = iter->second->SendMessageToClient(strMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient ClientID: %d not found", uClientid);
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    return bRet;
}

void WebSocketListener::setEventHandler(std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent)
{
    m_pEvent = pEvent;
}

// Start accepting incoming connections
void WebSocketListener::Run()
{
    do_accept();
}

void WebSocketListener::do_accept()
{
    try
    {
        // The new connection gets its own strand
        g_acceptor.async_accept(
            net::make_strand(g_ioc),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &WebSocketListener::on_accept,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::do_accept Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::do_accept Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketListener::on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
{
    try
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept accept failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s", socket.native_handle(), ec.message().c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true), ec);
            if (ec)
            {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept set_option(No delay) failed, error message: %s", ec.message().c_str());
                return;
            }

            std::string sClientIp = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
            unsigned short uiClientPort = socket.remote_endpoint().port();
            SOCKET socketId = socket.native_handle();
            // Create the WebSocketSession and run it
            std::shared_ptr<WebSocketSession> objSession = std::make_shared<WebSocketSession>(std::move(socket), g_ctx, m_pEvent, socketId);
            if (objSession != nullptr)
            {
                objSession->run();

                EnterCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);
                auto itr = m_mapClientidSession.find(socketId);
                if (itr != m_mapClientidSession.end())
                {
                    itr->second = objSession;
                    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept update client id : %d", socketId);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_mapClientidSession.insert(pair<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<WebSocketSession >>(socketId, objSession));
                    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept insert client id : %d", socketId);
                }
                LeaveCriticalSection(&m_hCSClientidSession);

                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketListener::on_accept Incoming connection request from SocketID: %d, IP: %s Port: %hu", socketId, sClientIp.c_str(), uiClientPort);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketListener::on_accept Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    // Accept another connection
    do_accept();
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Session class
WebSocketSession::WebSocketSession(tcp::socket&& socket, ssl::context& ctx, std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent, SOCKET socketId)
    : ws_(std::move(socket), ctx), m_pEvent(pEvent), m_SocketDescriptor(socketId)
{
    m_WriteBuffer.reserve(1000);
    m_ReadBuffer.reserve(1000);
    bHandShake = false;
}

WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession()
{
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession SocketID: %d Closing ", m_SocketDescriptor);
    if (ws_.is_open())
    {
        beast::websocket::close_reason closeReason;
        beast::error_code ec;
        ws_.close(closeReason, ec);
        if (ec)
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession SocketID: %d clsoing error msg: %s", ec.message().c_str());
    }
}

// Get on the correct executor
void WebSocketSession::run()
{
    try {
        // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
        // on the I/O objects in this WebSocketSession. Although not strictly necessary
        // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
        // thread-safe by default.
        net::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &WebSocketSession::on_run,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::run Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::run Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::closeSocket() 
{
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::closeSocket Closing SocketID: %d", m_SocketDescriptor);
    beast::websocket::close_reason closeReason;
    beast::error_code ec; 
    UINT ID = m_SocketDescriptor;
    ws_.async_close(closeReason, [=](beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::closeSocket SocketID: %d, Code: %d Message: %s", ID, closeReason, ec.message().c_str());
        }
    }
    );
}

// Start the asynchronous operation
void WebSocketSession::on_run()
{
    try
    {
        // Set the timeout.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::server,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &WebSocketSession::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_run Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_run Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
{
    try
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_handshake handshake failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s", m_SocketDescriptor, ec.message().c_str());
            return;
        }
        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
            websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res)
        {
            res.set(http::field::server,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                " websocket-server-async-ssl");
        }));

        http::async_read(ws_.next_layer(), m_ReadBuffer, g_upgrade_request,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &WebSocketSession::on_upgrade,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_handshake Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_handshake Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t)
{
    try
    {
        if (ec)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade upgrade failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s", m_SocketDescriptor, ec.message().c_str());
            return;
        }

        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Handshake completed for SocketID: %d, WebSocket Headers: %s", m_SocketDescriptor, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(g_upgrade_request.base()));

        if (m_pEvent != nullptr)
        {
            m_pEvent->OnConnect(m_SocketDescriptor, true, "", 0);
        }
        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
            g_upgrade_request,
            beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_accept(beast::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        do_Disconnect();
        return;
    }
    // Read a message
    do_read();
}

void WebSocketSession::do_read()
{
    static boost::mutex objMutex;
    try
    {
        objMutex.lock();
        if (m_pEvent && !bHandShake)
        {
            bHandShake = true;
            m_pEvent->onHandShake(m_SocketDescriptor, bHandShake);
        }
        // Read a message into our buffer
                
        ws_.async_read(
                m_ReadBuffer,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                    &WebSocketSession::on_read,
                    shared_from_this()));
        objMutex.unlock();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        objMutex.unlock();
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::do_read Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        objMutex.unlock();
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::do_read Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    try
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the WebSocketSession was closed
        if (ec == websocket::error::closed)
        {
            do_Disconnect();
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketSession::on_read Client closed  SocketID: %d", m_SocketDescriptor);
            return;
        }

        if (ec)
        {
            do_Disconnect();
            return;
        }

        if (m_pEvent != nullptr)
        {
            if (m_ReadBuffer.cdata().size() > 0)
            {
                const unsigned int iLen = m_ReadBuffer.cdata().size();
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "WebSocketSession::on_read Client SocketID: %d dataRecv: %d cpacity: %d", m_SocketDescriptor, iLen, m_ReadBuffer.capacity());
                
                std::shared_ptr<char> objData(new char[iLen], std::default_delete<char[]>());
                ::memset(objData.get(), 0, iLen);
                if (objData)
                {
                    memcpy(objData.get(), m_ReadBuffer.cdata().data(), iLen);
                    m_pEvent->OnReceive(m_SocketDescriptor, objData.get(), iLen);
                }
            }
        }
        m_ReadBuffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_read Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::on_read Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    do_read();
}

UINT WebSocketSession::getSocketDescriptor()
{
    return m_SocketDescriptor;
}

void testDelete(char* p) 
{
    delete[] p;
}

struct DeleteChar {
    void operator()(char* p) const {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
            "Deleting the buffer");
        delete[] p;
    }
};

bool WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient(std::string strMessage) 
{
    bool bRet = false;
    static std::mutex obj;
    try {
        obj.lock();
        
        if (strMessage.length() > 0)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %u, BufferCapacity: %u msgLen: %d, msg:%s",
                m_SocketDescriptor, m_WriteBuffer.size(), m_WriteBuffer.capacity(), strMessage.length(), strMessage.c_str());

            if (m_WriteBuffer.size() > 40960) // Pending data size is greater than 40 MB
            {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %u, Disconnecting client due to pending buffer limit crossed",
                    m_SocketDescriptor, m_WriteBuffer.size());
                do_Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                boost::beast::ostream(m_WriteBuffer) << strMessage << ":";

                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %u, BufferCapacity: %u",
                    m_SocketDescriptor, m_WriteBuffer.size(), m_WriteBuffer.capacity());

                ws_.async_write(m_WriteBuffer.data(),
                    [this](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t transfer)
                {
                    boost::ignore_unused(transfer);
                    if (ec)
                    {
                        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient callback error SocketID: %d, ErrorMsg:%s"/* ,Message: %s"*/, m_SocketDescriptor, ec.message().c_str()/*,strMessage.c_str()*/);

                        do_Disconnect();
                    }

                    obj.lock();
                    m_WriteBuffer.consume(transfer);
                    obj.unlock();
                });

                bRet = true;
            }
        }
        obj.unlock();
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        obj.unlock();
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        obj.unlock();
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::SendMessageToClient Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    return bRet;
}

void WebSocketSession::do_Disconnect()
{
    try {
        if (m_pEvent)
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                "WebSocketSession::do_Disconnect disconnecting SocketID: %d", m_SocketDescriptor);
            m_pEvent->OnConnect(m_SocketDescriptor, false, "", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                "WebSocketSession::do_Disconnect Removing SocketID: %d", m_SocketDescriptor);
            objWebSocketListener->RemoveClient(m_SocketDescriptor);
        }
    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::do_Disconnect Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "WebSocketSession::do_Disconnect Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code to *maybe* see where you invoke the [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Out on a limb I'd say the timer is destructed *after* the execution context is (e.g. `io_context`)

Comment: @sehe I have added the code and exception info. Please check it. What i am doing wrong. If needed please contact me on my email.
Mail id: lalit.sharma91@outlook.com

Comment: Stackoverflow is a q&a site. I prefer to use it because the help serves many more people. You could have guessed from the fact that this is where I answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just spent... hours getting your code fixed up enough so it compiles. I
remember doing the same when you posted it
https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1335 and your previous question.
Rough result [Live On
Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/106518c6286332c1)

The number of problems in the code is scarily high.

- Sockets aren't `UINT`,
- they're not unique during the lifetime of a process,
- a local mutex will not protect anything,
- the majority of format specifiers are wrong,
- some format arguments are missing,
- some are invoking UB by passing non-trivial objects through varargs,
- concurrency hints are not numbers of threads,
- the threads just run wild (detached),
- strands should actually remove the need for critical sections,
- `maxThreads` is unused,
- there will necessarily always be a race condition around start of the listener and setting the event handlers,
- all the sessions share the `g_upgrade_request` variable - regardless of threading even - that's just a data race and therefore [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior);
- the mix of WIN32 API, boost and standard library threading primitives suggests that all of the code is basically copy-pasted from random sources.

Regardless of everything, your original stacktrace (which you removed?) showed a timer completion. That implies the source is a socket operation on `ws_` timing out (since you don't have any other timers):

```
beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
```

And that probably happens after the `g_io` instance is destructed. That's completely expected since all your IO threads are... detached, so they will happily continue to run after `main` exits.

So, make sure your main doesn't exit before the execution context runs out of work. Better yet, don't make that a global anyways.

---

## Friends Don't Let Friends Use Globals

Just fixing everything by applying basic scope hygiene

- moving most things into the listener
- moving the upgrade request into the session
- using `thread_pool` to avoid doing the manually threads (poorly as well)
- adding `Stop` that waits
- removing the useless mutexes in favor of the strands - you were trying to use them anyways
- relying on the `shared_from_this` (that you... were using anyways) by
  storing `weak_ptr` in your sessions map. Note the session map no longer
  requires the unsafe key either
- improved and simplified error handling

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4f00cdd5deeb66c)**

```cpp
#if 0
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the WEBSOCKETSERVER_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// WEBSOCKETSERVER_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
    #ifdef WEBSOCKETSERVER_EXPORTS
        #define WEBSOCKETSERVER_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define WEBSOCKETSERVER_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    #include "TSWebSocket.h"
    #include "server_certificate.hpp"
#else
    #include <cstdarg>
    #include <cstdio>
    #define WEBSOCKETSERVER_API
    #define STDCALL // __stdcall

namespace stl::log {
    enum { LOG_GROUP_ERROR };
    enum { LOG_LEVEL_INFO, LOG_LEVEL_ERROR };
    [[gnu::format(printf, 3, 4)]] void trace([[maybe_unused]] auto section, [[maybe_unused]] auto level,
                                             [[maybe_unused]] char const* fmt, ...) {
        std::va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, fmt);
        std::vfprintf(stderr, fmt, argptr);
        std::puts(""); // poor man's newline
        va_end(argptr);
    }
} // namespace stl::log

#endif

#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <string_view>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

namespace beast     = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;     // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl       = boost::asio::ssl;     // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp           = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

static void load_server_certificate(ssl::context& ctx, std::string, std::string) {
    // TODO
    ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.use_private_key_file("server.pem", ssl::context::pem);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    ctx.set_password_callback([](size_t, auto /*purpose*/) { return "test"; });
}

using SOCKET = tcp::socket::native_handle_type;
struct ISocketEvents {
    virtual ~ISocketEvents() = default;
    virtual void OnConnect(SOCKET, bool, std::string_view, int) {
        stl::log::trace(0, 0, "Event handler: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
    virtual void onHandShake(SOCKET, bool) {
        stl::log::trace(0, 0, "Event handler: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
    virtual void OnReceive(SOCKET, char const*, size_t) {
        stl::log::trace(0, 0, "Event handler: %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    }
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class WebSocketSession;
// Accepts incoming connections and launches the sessions
class WEBSOCKETSERVER_API WebSocketListener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<WebSocketListener> {
  private:
    using Handle = std::weak_ptr<WebSocketSession>;
    std::list<Handle>              m_sessions;
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> m_pEvent;

    boost::asio::thread_pool m_ctx;
    tcp::acceptor            m_acceptor{net::make_strand(m_ctx)};

  public:
    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context m_sslctx{
        ssl::context::tlsv12}; // TODO make private, probably by moving load_server_certificate

    WebSocketListener(tcp::endpoint endpoint, size_t num_threads);
    ~WebSocketListener();
    void Run();
    void Stop();
    void setEventHandler(std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent);
    bool SendMessageToClient(SOCKET uClientid, std::string strMessage);

  private:
    void do_accept();
    void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket);
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class WebSocketSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<WebSocketSession> {
    websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;

    beast::flat_buffer               m_ReadBuffer;
    beast::flat_buffer               m_WriteBuffer;
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents>   m_pEvent;
    bool                             bHandShake = false;
    http::request<http::string_body> m_upgrade_request;
    beast::websocket::close_reason   m_closeReason{};

  public:
    // Take ownership of the socket
    WebSocketSession(tcp::socket socket, ssl::context& ctx, std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent);
    ~WebSocketSession();
    void   run();
    void   closeSocket();
    void   on_run();
    void   on_handshake(beast::error_code ec);
    void   on_accept(beast::error_code ec);
    void   on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t);
    void   do_read();
    void   on_read(beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);
    SOCKET getId();
    void   SendMessage(std::string strMessage);
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Factory function that creates instances of the Server Protocol object.
WEBSOCKETSERVER_API std::shared_ptr<WebSocketListener> STDCALL InitializeWebSocketListener( //
    unsigned short port, int maxThreads, std::string certificate, std::string privateKey,
    std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> handlers);
//--------
//

// It initialize the WebSocketListener
std::shared_ptr<WebSocketListener>
    STDCALL InitializeWebSocketListener(unsigned short port, int maxThreads, std::string certificate,
                                        std::string privateKey, std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> handlers) {

    // Create and launch a listening port
    auto obj = std::make_shared<WebSocketListener>(tcp::endpoint{{}, port}, maxThreads);
    obj->setEventHandler(handlers);
    obj->Run();
    load_server_certificate(obj->m_sslctx, certificate, privateKey);

    return obj;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Listener class
WebSocketListener::~WebSocketListener() {}

WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener(tcp::endpoint endpoint, size_t num_threads) : m_ctx(num_threads) {
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Constructor Enter");
    beast::error_code ec;

    // Open the acceptor
    m_acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol(), ec);
    if (ec) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener open failed, error message: %s",
                        ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Allow address reuse
    m_acceptor.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
    if (ec) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener set_option failed, error message: %s",
                        ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    m_acceptor.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true), ec);
    if (ec) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener set_option(No delay) failed, error message: %s",
                        ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Bind to the server address
    m_acceptor.bind(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener bind failed, error message: %s",
                        ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }

    // Start listening for connections
    m_acceptor.listen(net::socket_base::max_listen_connections, ec);
    if (ec) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener listen failed, error message: %s",
                        ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    } else {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO,
                        "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Started listening at %s:%hu",
                        m_acceptor.local_endpoint().address().to_string().c_str(),
                        m_acceptor.local_endpoint().port());
    }

    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketListener::WebSocketListener Constructor Leave");
}

bool WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient(SOCKET uClientid, std::string strMessage) {
    try {
        // TODO maybe make `m_sessions` a map again
        for (Handle const& handle : m_sessions) {
            if (auto session = handle.lock()) {
                if (session->getId() != uClientid)
                    continue;

                session->SendMessage(strMessage);
                return true;
            }
        }
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient ClientID: %d not found", uClientid);
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::SendMessageToClient Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    return false;
}

void WebSocketListener::setEventHandler(std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent) {
    net::post(m_acceptor.get_executor(), // post on strand
              [this, pEvent, self = shared_from_this()] { m_pEvent = pEvent; });
}

// Start accepting incoming connections
void WebSocketListener::Run() {
    net::post(m_acceptor.get_executor(),          // post on strand
              [this, self = shared_from_this()] { //
                  do_accept();
              });
}

void WebSocketListener::Stop() {
    net::post(m_acceptor.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
        m_acceptor.cancel();
        for (Handle& handle : m_sessions)
            if (auto session = handle.lock())
                session->closeSocket();
    });
    m_ctx.join(); // waits for all IO to finish
}

void WebSocketListener::do_accept() {
    m_acceptor.async_accept( //
        net::make_strand(m_ctx),
        beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketListener::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
}

void WebSocketListener::on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
    try {
        if (ec) {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketListener::on_accept accept failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s",
                            socket.native_handle(), ec.message().c_str());
        } else {
            // Accept another connection
            do_accept();

            socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true), ec);
            if (ec) {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                "WebSocketListener::on_accept set_option(No delay) failed, error message: %s",
                                ec.message().c_str());
                return;
            }

            std::string    sClientIp    = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
            unsigned short uiClientPort = socket.remote_endpoint().port();

            // Create the WebSocketSession and run it
            auto session = std::make_shared<WebSocketSession>(std::move(socket), m_sslctx, m_pEvent);

            m_sessions.emplace_back(session);
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketListener::on_accept insert client id : %d", session->getId());

            // optionally: garbage collect expired sessions
            m_sessions.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&Handle::expired));

            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO,
                            "WebSocketListener::on_accept Incoming connection request from SocketID: %d, "
                            "IP: %s Port: %hu",
                            session->getId(), sClientIp.c_str(), uiClientPort);

            session->run();
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::on_accept Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketListener::on_accept Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Session class
WebSocketSession::WebSocketSession(tcp::socket socket, ssl::context& ctx,
                                   std::shared_ptr<ISocketEvents> pEvent)
    : ws_(std::move(socket), ctx)
    , m_pEvent(pEvent) //
{
    m_WriteBuffer.reserve(1000);
    m_ReadBuffer.reserve(1000);
}

WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession() try {
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession SocketID: %d Closing ", getId());
    if (ws_.is_open()) {
        beast::error_code ec;
        ws_.close(m_closeReason, ec);
        if (ec)
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketSession::~WebSocketSession SocketID: %d clsoing error msg: %s",
                    getId(), ec.message().c_str());
        if (m_pEvent)
            m_pEvent->OnConnect(getId(), false, "", 0);
    }
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
            "~WebSocketSession Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
} catch (...) {
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
            "~WebSocketSession Inside Generic Catch");
}

// Get on the correct executor
void WebSocketSession::run() {
    // We need to be executing within a strand to perform async operations
    // on the I/O objects in this WebSocketSession. Although not strictly necessary
    // for single-threaded contexts, this example code is written to be
    // thread-safe by default.
    net::dispatch(ws_.get_executor(),
            beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_run, shared_from_this()));
}

void WebSocketSession::closeSocket() {
    auto id = getId();
    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                    "WebSocketSession::closeSocket Closing SocketID: %d", id);

    auto self = shared_from_this();
    //// ideally we cleanly close, however this will not reliably close the pending read
    // net::post(ws_.get_executor(), [this, self] { get_lowest_layer(ws_).cancel(); });

    net::post(ws_.get_executor(), [this, self, id] {
        // m_closeReason must stay valid!
        ws_.async_close(m_closeReason, [self, id](beast::error_code ec) {
            if (ec) {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                "WebSocketSession::closeSocket SocketID: %d Message: %s", id,
                                ec.message().c_str());
            }
        });
    });
}

// Start the asynchronous operation
void WebSocketSession::on_run() {
    // Set the timeout.
    beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    // Perform the SSL handshake
    ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
        ssl::stream_base::server,
        beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_handshake, shared_from_this()));
}

void WebSocketSession::on_handshake(beast::error_code ec) {
    try {
        if (ec) {
            stl::log::trace(
                stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                "WebSocketSession::on_handshake handshake failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s", getId(),
                ec.message().c_str());
            return;
        }
        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::response_type& res) {
            res.set(http::field::server,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-server-async-ssl");
        }));

        http::async_read(ws_.next_layer(), m_ReadBuffer, m_upgrade_request,
                         beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_upgrade, shared_from_this()));
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_handshake Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_handshake Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t) {
    try {
        if (ec) {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade upgrade failed, error SocketID: %d, message: %s",
                            getId(), ec.message().c_str());
            return;
        }

        stl::log::trace(
            stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO,
            "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Handshake completed for SocketID: %d, WebSocket Headers: %s",
            getId(), boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(m_upgrade_request.base()).c_str());

        if (m_pEvent)
            m_pEvent->OnConnect(getId(), true, "", 0);

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(m_upgrade_request,
                         beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_upgrade Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (!ec)
        do_read(); // Read a message
}

void WebSocketSession::do_read() {
    try {
        if (m_pEvent && !bHandShake) {
            bHandShake = true;
            m_pEvent->onHandShake(getId(), bHandShake);
        }
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws_.async_read(m_ReadBuffer,
                       beast::bind_front_handler(&WebSocketSession::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::do_read Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::do_read Inside Generic Catch");
    }
}

void WebSocketSession::on_read(beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    try {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        // This indicates that the WebSocketSession was closed
        if (ec) {
            if (ec == websocket::error::closed) {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO,
                                "WebSocketSession::on_read Client closed SocketID: %d", getId());
            }
            return;
        }

        if (auto iLen = m_ReadBuffer.cdata().size()) {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_INFO,
                    "WebSocketSession::on_read Client SocketID: %d dataRecv: %zu cpacity: %zu",
                    getId(), iLen, m_ReadBuffer.capacity());

            std::string data(net::buffer_cast<char const*>(m_ReadBuffer.cdata()), iLen);
            if (m_pEvent)
                m_pEvent->OnReceive(getId(), data.data(), iLen);
        }
        m_ReadBuffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {

        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_read Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
    } catch (...) {
        stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                        "WebSocketSession::on_read Inside Generic Catch");
    }
    do_read();
}

SOCKET WebSocketSession::getId() { return beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().native_handle(); }

void WebSocketSession::SendMessage(std::string strMessage) {
    net::post(ws_.get_executor(), [this, msg = std::move(strMessage), self=shared_from_this()] {
        try {
            if (msg.length() > 0) {
                stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                "WebSocketSession::SendMessage SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %zu, "
                                "BufferCapacity: %zu msgLen:%zud, msg:%s",
                                getId(), m_WriteBuffer.size(), m_WriteBuffer.capacity(), msg.length(),
                                msg.c_str());

                if (m_WriteBuffer.size() > 40960) // Pending data size is greater than 40 MB
                {
                    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                    "WebSocketSession::SendMessage SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %zu, "
                                    "Disconnecting client due to pending buffer limit crossed",
                                    getId(), m_WriteBuffer.size());
                } else {
                    boost::beast::ostream(m_WriteBuffer) << msg << ":";

                    stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                    "WebSocketSession::SendMessage SocketID: %d, BufferSize: %zu, "
                                    "BufferCapacity: %zu",
                                    getId(), m_WriteBuffer.size(), m_WriteBuffer.capacity());

                    ws_.async_write(m_WriteBuffer.data(), [this](beast::error_code ec, size_t transferred) {
                        boost::ignore_unused(transferred);
                        if (ec) {
                            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                                            "WebSocketSession::SendMessage callback error SocketID: %d, "
                                            "ErrorMsg:%s" /* ,Message: %s"*/,
                                            getId(), ec.message().c_str() /*,msg.c_str()*/);

                        }

                        m_WriteBuffer.consume(transferred);
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketSession::SendMessage Inside Catch msg: %s", e.what());
        } catch (...) {
            stl::log::trace(stl::log::LOG_GROUP_ERROR, stl::log::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            "WebSocketSession::SendMessage Inside Generic Catch");
        }
    });
}

int main() {
    auto handlers = std::make_shared<ISocketEvents>();
    auto wsl      = InitializeWebSocketListener(8989, 50, "CERT", "KEY", handlers);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    wsl->Stop();
}
```

With a local demo:

[image]

### Summary, Caveats

In summary, be way more aware of lifetimes (see `m_closeReason` for the subtler ones) and shutdown.

Issues remaining:

- `closeSocket()` partly depends on the peer actively cooperating according to Websocket specification. You might want to extend with logic to forcibly close the socket eventually
- you need more safety surrounding `SendMessage` - currently it is entirely possible to issue overlapping writes. That's... against the specs. You can solve that by putting an outgoing message queue in there

Comment: thanks for your effort and time. I really appreciated it. I will work on the points which you highlighted.

Comment: I have voted it but still it is pending because I don't have 15 reputations at the current moment.

Comment: i have implemented the message queue in the code like this:-

1. We insert message into queue and checked if size is one then we send it using async. otherwise we added it to queue.
2. When we receive a callback we check the queue size if it is greater than 1. We do pop and send another message using async. but there is one case when we received messages very fast then pending queue size increased rapidly for a client.

What can we do for this case in boost?

Comment: That sounds about right (assuming some of the wording is just unfortunately confusing). "What can we do for this case in boost" - this has nothing to do with boost. You have to put a limit in code, just like you would without boost.

Comment: I am getting the following errors sometimes. can you please suggest why it is coming?
1. short read (SSL routines, SSL routines).
2. The semaphore timeout period has expired.
3. The WebSocket close frame reason code was invalid.

How i can resolve these? Thanks in advance.